# Modify a multi index pandas data frame in place multiplying by scalar

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi index data frame similar to

```
                      value       identifier

EA    2007-01-01      0.33            55
      2007-01-01      0.73            56
      2007-01-01      0.51            57
      2007-02-01      0.13            55
      2007-02-01      0.23            57
      2007-03-01      0.82            55
      2007-03-01      0.88            56
      2007-03-01      0.19            57
      2008-01-01      0.36            55
      2008-01-01      0.26            57
      2008-02-01      0.17            55
      2008-02-01      0.17            56
      2008-02-01      0.57            57
      2008-03-01      0.75            55
      2008-03-01      0.45            56
EB    2007-01-01      0.13            55
      2007-01-01      0.74            56
      2007-01-01      0.56            57
      2007-02-01      0.93            55
      2007-02-01      0.23            57
      2007-03-01      0.82            55
      2007-03-01      0.38            56
      2007-03-01      0.19            57
      2008-01-01      0.46            55
      2008-01-01      0.26            57
      2008-02-01      0.67            55
      2008-02-01      0.98            56
      2008-02-01      0.11            57
      2008-03-01      0.75            55
      2008-03-01      0.22            56
```

and a dict with the values

```
weights = {"EA":0.1, "EB":0.7}
```

I'm trying to multiply all values by the weights. The first obvious way to do it was

```
for key, weight in weigths.items():
    df[key]['value'] = df[key]['value'] * weight
```

But this gave a warning:

```
 SettingWithCopyWarning: 
 A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
 Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So I tried this instead:

```
for key, weight in weigths.items():
    df.loc[key,'value'] = df.loc[key,'value'] * weight
```

But then it couldn't find the column `value`. This form works, but it gives the same warning:

```
for key, weight in weigths.items():
    df.loc[key]['value'] = df.loc[key]['value'] * weight
```

Based on the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), I understand the reason why this warning might be relevant, but then how can I multiply the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't your immediate question but I'd take a different approach on this question which ought to run much faster:

```
df['wt'] = df['index'].map(weights)

df

   index        date  value  identifier   wt
0     EA  2007-01-01   0.33          55  0.1
1     EA  2007-01-01   0.73          56  0.1
2     EA  2007-01-01   0.51          57  0.1

...

15    EB  2007-01-01   0.13          55  0.7
16    EB  2007-01-01   0.74          56  0.7
17    EB  2007-01-01   0.56          57  0.7
```

I'm assuming EA/EB is in a column called 'index', so you may have to reset_index before doing that.

From there, it's just regular multiplication.

```
df[['value','identifier']].mul(df['wt'],axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you can see on my original data frame, the column with the EA, EB doesn't have a name. What can I do in this case?

Comment: It can vary, just do `df = df.reset_index()` and see how it is labelled.  For simple index will just be 'index' but I think you will see 'level_0' and 'level_1' if it's a multi-index (and if they previously were named columns, they should revert to those names).

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to follow this route. I did this and I'm getting MemoryError.

Comment: You might also be be able to use the map directly on the index without resetting, but given that it's a multi-index I generally find it much easier to work (syntax-wise) with a specific column rather than a specified level of a multi-index.  FWIW.

Comment: Memory error?  Huh, that is weird but I have no idea how big your data or computer is...  If it's on the multiplication part, you might need to do it column by column instead of all at once?  I wouldn't think the mapping itsel would have any significant memory footprint.

Comment: Interesting. The memory error happens if I try to get a data frame out of it, using the [[ ]] notation. I can bypass the Memory Error if I create a new column with the multiplication product. BTW, the axis=0 is not necessary, right? PS: the computer is quite bad :-)

Comment: You don't need the `axis=0` if you are multiplying 2 series, but you may in other cases like multiplying 2 columns of a dataframe by a series.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the self-explanatory warning, do this:

```
df['value'][key] = df['value'][key] * 1000000
```

Don't see any warnings with pandas version (0.16):

```
In [891]: df
Out[891]: 
               value  identifier
ind1 ind2                       
EA   01/01/07   0.33          55
     01/01/07   0.73          56
     01/01/07   0.51          57
     01/02/07   0.13          55
     01/02/07   0.23          57
     01/03/07   0.82          55
     01/03/07   0.88          56
     01/03/07   0.19          57
     01/01/08   0.36          55
     01/01/08   0.26          57
     01/02/08   0.17          55
     01/02/08   0.17          56
     01/02/08   0.57          57
     01/03/08   0.75          55
     01/03/08   0.45          56
EB   01/01/07   0.13          55
     01/01/07   0.74          56
     01/01/07   0.56          57
     01/02/07   0.93          55
     01/02/07   0.23          57
     01/03/07   0.82          55
     01/03/07   0.38          56
     01/03/07   0.19          57
     01/01/08   0.46          55
     01/01/08   0.26          57
     01/02/08   0.67          55

In [892]: df.loc['EA']['value'] = df.loc['EA']['value'] * weights[k]

In [893]: df
Out[893]: 
               value  identifier
ind1 ind2                       
EA   01/01/07  0.231          55
     01/01/07  0.511          56
     01/01/07  0.357          57
     01/02/07  0.091          55
     01/02/07  0.161          57
     01/03/07  0.574          55
     01/03/07  0.616          56
     01/03/07  0.133          57
     01/01/08  0.252          55
     01/01/08  0.182          57
     01/02/08  0.119          55
     01/02/08  0.119          56
     01/02/08  0.399          57
     01/03/08  0.525          55
     01/03/08  0.315          56
EB   01/01/07  0.130          55
     01/01/07  0.740          56
     01/01/07  0.560          57
     01/02/07  0.930          55
     01/02/07  0.230          57
     01/03/07  0.820          55
     01/03/07  0.380          56
     01/03/07  0.190          57
     01/01/08  0.460          55
     01/01/08  0.260          57
     01/02/08  0.670          55
```

Also, you can multiply a dataframe with a scalar value like this:

```
In [894]: df.multiply(500, level=1)
Out[894]: 
               value  identifier
ind1 ind2                       
EA   01/01/07  115.5       27500
     01/01/07  255.5       28000
     01/01/07  178.5       28500
     01/02/07   45.5       27500
     01/02/07   80.5       28500
     01/03/07  287.0       27500
     01/03/07  308.0       28000
     01/03/07   66.5       28500
     01/01/08  126.0       27500
     01/01/08   91.0       28500
     01/02/08   59.5       27500
     01/02/08   59.5       28000
     01/02/08  199.5       28500
     01/03/08  262.5       27500
     01/03/08  157.5       28000
EB   01/01/07   65.0       27500
     01/01/07  370.0       28000
     01/01/07  280.0       28500
     01/02/07  465.0       27500
     01/02/07  115.0       28500
     01/03/07  410.0       27500
     01/03/07  190.0       28000
     01/03/07   95.0       28500
     01/01/08  230.0       27500
     01/01/08  130.0       28500
     01/02/08  335.0       27500
```

Comment: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame, so no luck yet.

Comment: Which pandas version are you using ?

Comment: p.__version__ : 0.16.0

Comment: My multi index data frame doesn't have names like ind1 and ind2 in your example. This shouldn't be a problem, though. The multiply approach would multiply all values by the scalar, and I need just one column.

Comment: @Ivan you can multiply a single column like: `df['value'].multiply(500, level=1)` as well.

Comment: Yeah, but how to multiply by the different EA, EB?

Comment: Like this : `df.ix['EB']['value'].multiply(500, level=1)`